# No kernel updates in over a month debian unstable

Tags: debian, kernel

I havent gotten any kernel updates in over a month on Debian unstable, which seems like a long time for the unstable distribution. My output of uname -a shows:

`5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

As you can see, the compilation time is August 3. Is this normal? I'm used to constantly getting kernel updates in unstable. This also coincides with the release of Debian 11, maybe that has something to do with it.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks fine to me:

```
deb http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal; you have the latest kernel available in unstable.

Newer kernels have been [uploaded to experimental](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/linux).

I imagine that kernels will start going to unstable soon, now that Debian 11 has been released; but I don’t know the timeline. As you surmise, kernel updates in unstable were only those intended for Debian 11, right up to the release; all others went to experimental. It’s possible that the kernel team are continuing this distinction for a little while after the release, to make any patches for Debian 11 simpler to review.